# How to define run once context steps with Gauge?

Tags: testing, bdd, getgauge

Using [Gauge](https://gauge.org) we can repeat a set of steps before each scenario using [Context Steps](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/writing-specifications.html#longstart-context) right after a test specification heading. For example:

```
Delete project
==============
* User log in as "mike"

Delete single project
---------------------
* Delete the "example" project
* Ensure "example" project has been deleted

Delete multiple projects
------------------------
* Delete all the projects in the list
* Ensure project list is empty
```

In the above Delete Project test specification, the context step **User log in as "mike"** is going to be executed twice, one time for each of the two detete scenarios.

How to define steps that run once and before all scenarios of a test specification?

Comment: As a workaround, the implementation of the highlighted step could check if the user is already logged in as "mike" to avoid redoing log in

Comment: Not at the moment, I'm afraid. Related issue: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/805. Please post your thoughts on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have it run once through the spec file a workaround could be to use the suite store.

```
public void loginAsMike(){
  if((boolean) DataStoreFactory.getSuiteDataStore().get('loggedIn')){
      //execute steps
      DataStoreFactory.getSuiteDataStore().put('loggedIn', true);
  }
}
```

This way it will only run once. The only issue here would be if you were to run multiple tests in parallel. However if your only logging in as mike in one spec file only then this is a good solution.

Comment: Think about it now you could use spec store since it would only be in one file. So instead of DataStoreFactory.getSuiteDataStore() you would use DataStoreFactory.getSpecDataStore()